# Why i can't access the interface method in my dart class?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, error-handling

InterFace :

```
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

/// An interface for observing the behavior of [Bloc] instances.
class BlocObserver {
  /// Called whenever a [Bloc] is instantiated.
  /// In many cases, a cubit may be lazily instantiated and
  /// [onCreate] can be used to observe exactly when the cubit
  /// instance is created.
  @protected
  @mustCallSuper
  void onCreate(BlocBase bloc) {}

  /// Called whenever an [event] is `added` to any [bloc] with the given [bloc]
  /// and [event].
  @protected
  @mustCallSuper
  void onEvent(Bloc bloc, Object? event) {}

  /// Called whenever a [Change] occurs in any [bloc]
  /// A [change] occurs when a new state is emitted.
  /// [onChange] is called before a bloc's state has been updated.
  @protected
  @mustCallSuper
  void onChange(BlocBase bloc, Change change) {}

  /// Called whenever a transition occurs in any [bloc] with the given [bloc]
  /// and [transition].
  /// A [transition] occurs when a new `event` is `added` and `mapEventToState`
  /// executed.
  /// [onTransition] is called before a [bloc]'s state has been updated.
  @protected
  @mustCallSuper
  void onTransition(Bloc bloc, Transition transition) {}

  /// Called whenever an [error] is thrown in any [Bloc] or [Cubit].
  /// The [stackTrace] argument may be [StackTrace.empty] if an error
  /// was received without a stack trace.
  @protected
  @mustCallSuper
  void onError(BlocBase bloc, Object error, StackTrace stackTrace) {}
  void onError2(Object error, StackTrace stackTrace) {}
  void onError3(Object error) {}
  @mustCallSuper
  void hello(Object error) {}

  /// Called whenever a [Bloc] is closed.
  /// [onClose] is called just before the [Bloc] is closed
  /// and indicates that the particular instance will no longer
  /// emit new states.
  @protected
  @mustCallSuper
  void onClose(BlocBase bloc) {}
}
```

Class:

```
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';

class SimpleBlocObserver extends BlocObserver {
  @override
  void onChange(BlocBase bloc, Change change) {
    super.onChange(bloc, change);
    print('${bloc.runtimeType} $change');
  }

  @override
  void onCreate(BlocBase bloc) {
    super.onCreate(bloc);
    print("Block creat");
  }

  @override
  void onEvent(Bloc bloc, Object event) {
    super.onEvent(bloc, event);
    print(event);
  }

  @override
  void onTransition(Bloc bloc, Transition transition) {
    super.onTransition(bloc, transition);
    print(transition);
  }

  @override
  void onError(BlocBase bloc, Object error, StackTrace stackTrace) {
    super.onError(bloc, error, stackTrace);
    print(error);
  }

  @override
  void onError2(Object error, StackTrace stackTrace) {
    super.onError2(error, stackTrace);
    print(error);
  }

  @override
  void onError3(Object error) {
    super.onError3(error);
    print(error);
  }

  @override
  void onClose(BlocBase bloc) {
    super.onClose(bloc);
    print("Bloc close");
  }
}
```

Errors :

1. The method 'onError2' isn't defined in a superclass of 'SimpleBlocObserver'.
   Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'onError2' in a superclass.

2)The method 'onError3' isn't defined in a superclass of 'SimpleBlocObserver'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'onError3' in a superclass.

Comment: Does the `.dart` file that defines `SimpleBlocObserver` import the `.dart` file that defines `BlocObserver `?  Are you sure that there weren't other errors reported?

Comment: Yes block.dart file have BlocObserver  class And there is no any other errors

Comment: [`BlocObserver` from `package:bloc`](https://pub.dev/documentation/bloc/latest/bloc/BlocObserver-class.html) does not seem to have `onError2` and `onError3` methods.  Where did you copy and paste the interface code from?